# Запятая (тире, двоеточие) в предложениях типа "Ты имеешь в виду [что-то]?"

Tags: пунктуация

Я не совсем понимаю, когда ставится запятая/тире/двоеточие, когда — нет. Возможно, дело в согласованности или несогласованности, но не уверен.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

- — Ты имеешь в виду "Метрополь"?
- — Ты имеешь в виду — расти над собой?
- ― Ма, ты имеешь в виду: стерпится, слюбится?
- ― Ты имеешь в виду, в МОЕЙ комнате?
- — Ты имеешь в виду, как работает эта штуковина?

Comment: Элементы зрительно перегружены, imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вот обычные предложения:

*Ты имеешь в виду **конец света**, спросил Арсений.* [Евгений Водолазкин. Лавр (2012)]

― *Ты имеешь в виду, **что и их подкупят**?* [Максим Милованов. Естественный отбор (2000)]

Никаких знаков нет, сочетание употребляется в соответствии со своим значением, указанным во фразеологическом словаре:

**ИМЕТЬ В ВИДУ**. 1. кого, что. **Подразумевать кого-либо, что-либо**. Я многих черепах имею здесь в виду. Нам помощь скорая нужна подчас в делах, Но горе, коль она в руках у черепах! (С. Михалков. Заяц и Черепаха). 2. кого, что. **Принимать во внимание.** Имейте в виду, задание ответственное (И. Эренбург. Буря). 3. что. **Замышлять, намереваться** (что-либо сделать). Воропаев старался убедить Софью Ивановну, что он, беря в аренду дом, никогда не имел в виду… жить с его доходов, а хотел только одного — иметь свой угол (П. Павленко. Счастье).

2. Оборот может присоединять **дополнение или придаточное** изъяснительное предложение (союз ЧТО или союзные слова КАК и др.):

*— Ты имеешь в виду **"Метрополь"**?*

*– Ты имеешь в виду, **как работает эта штуковина**?*

2 . Если оборот относится  **к словосочетанию**, то его желательно выделить: в устной речи паузой, а на письме одним из знаков (запятая, двоеточие, тире).

Выбор знака определяется **интонацией**. Запятая обозначает небольшую паузу, а тире и двоеточие – это более сильные знаки. При использовании двоеточия пауза особо подчеркивается (интонационное предупреждение о последующем пояснении). При отсутствии такой затянутой паузы ставится тире:

― *Ты имеешь в виду, в МОЕЙ комнате?*

*― Ма, ты имеешь в виду: стерпится, слюбится?*

*— Ты имеешь в виду — расти над собой?*